# Display Item Count in Quick Edit mode

Tags: column, datasheet, quick-edit

Is there any way to display column count in Quick Edit mode? Datasheet view had this option to "Show Totals" but this seems to be missing with Quick Edit

Comment: Quick edit mode? Are you referring to List Views?

Comment: @ThinkB4Code Yes,the alternative of Datasheet view in SPO

Answer (score 2):

To get the item count of list, just send a REST query to list `ItemCount` endpoint. It will provide you with the count of items in list. After that you can place the data where ever you like in the page.

Following is the code to achieve the same:

```
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    function getListItemCount(listTitle){
        var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/ItemCount"
        $.getJSON(url, function(data){
            $(".ms-csrlistview-controldiv").append("<div>Item Count: " + data.value + "<div>")
        })
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        getListItemCount('TestList');
    })
</script>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Just place the code in a `script editor web part` and you are good to go.

Comment: Will this work on the quick edit mode / datasheet view?

Comment: Yes this will work. The AJAX call is to get the Item Count. You can place it anywhere in the UI. Since I used modified OOTB list view all item, i picked `$(".ms-csrlistview-controldiv")` selector to place the data. You need to change the selector as per your requirement.

Comment: This works.I really wonder why this OOB feature was removed with Quick Edit. :( What does the value of integrity and crossorigin mean in the script?

Comment: Both are the attribute used when you are referring styles/scripts from CDN. Refer to this URL to learn more. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity

Comment: This solution does not update the count if we filter on a column