# SharePoint 2013 list Quick Edit mode missing functions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

Is there a way to implement these missing functions in SharePoint 2013 on-premises list Quick Edit mode?

1. Aggregation (SUM, COUNT etc). There is an [article](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/221163/display-item-count-in-quick-edit-mode) that implements this but it does not work when we use/change header filters. It is possible to pass the filter to the REST query but problem is how to know the filtered column and its value from the js grid.
2. When click on the header, the filter does not display any data. This happens when data grows large.

Please see image below. There is no Count on "Account No." column. The "Title" column has no data to filter. There are around 8k items in the list.

[image]